# Nested query in a select statement for counting entries based on fields derived from the outer query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm struggling with a thing that in my mind should be achievable but I can't get it to work...here the scenario:

I have two tables structured as follows:

1- table where data are logged every 10 minutes: (tab_cycle)

```
timestamp      | value1 | value2 ... | valueN
20140715 10:10 |   10   |   20   ... |   x
20140715 10:00 |   14   |   45   ... |   x
```

2 - table where data are logged with an event driven structure (tab_event)

```
timestamp      | descr  |  value
20140715 10:09 |   a    |    10
20140715 10:04 |   a    |    14
20140715 10:00 |   a    |    11
20140715 09:59 |   a    |    10
20140715 09:54 |   a    |    20
```

Now what I want to achieve **(if it is possible)** without the need of using a cursor being able to create a select statement that is gonna produce the following result:

```
timestamp      | value1 | value2 ... | valueN |countEvent
20140715 10:10 |   10   |   20   ... |   x    |   null
20140715 10:00 |   14   |   45   ... |   x    |    3
```

so basically count the number of time a selected event with a selected tag is generated within the timestamp and timestamp + 10min.

What i tried was the following but without much success:

```
SELECT tab_cycle.timestamp AS startTime, DATEADD(mi, 10, tab_cycle.timestamp) AS endTime, 
(SELECT COUNT(tab_event.descr) FROM tab_event  WHERE tab_event.timestamp BETWEEN tab_cycle.timestamp and DATEADD(mi, 10, tab_cycle.timestamp) AND tab_event.tag LIKE  'A' GROUP BY tag) AS eventCounter 
FROM tab_cycle
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `group by` in the nested subquery:

```
SELECT tab_cycle.timestamp AS startTime, DATEADD(mm, 10, tab_cycle.timestamp) AS endTime, 
       (SELECT COUNT(tab_event.descr)
        FROM tab_event
        WHERE tab_event.timestamp BETWEEN tab_cycle.timestamp and
                                          DATEADD(mm, 10, tab_cycle.timestamp) AND
              tab_event.tag LIKE 'A'
       ) AS eventCounter 
FROM tab_cycle
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

EDIT:

I was actually thinking of adding this code anyway.  The answer to your question -- if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later is to use `lead()`:

```
SELECT tc.timestamp AS startTime, DATEADD(mm, 10, tc.timestamp) AS endTime, 
       (SELECT COUNT(te.descr)
        FROM tab_event te
        WHERE te.timestamp BETWEEN tc.timestamp and tc.next_timestamp AND
              te.tag LIKE 'A'
       ) AS eventCounter 
FROM (SELECT tc.*, LEAD(tc.timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY tc.timestamp) as next_timestamp 
      FROM tab_cycle tc
     ) tc
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

I also added abbreviations for the table names.  These make the query easier to write and read.

If you are using an older version of SQL Server, you would do the same thing with a correlated subquery or using `cross apply`.

Comment: Nice and tanks, it did the trick! Kindly one more question than, if the delta time between the cycles is variable, is it possible to do a difference between the timestamp at cycle N and the timestamp at cycle N-1 instead of the fixed 10 minutes that I'm doing with the DATEADD?

Comment: Thanks again also for the second reply much appreciated, LEAD is indeed a very powerful instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I may have the datediff backwards

```
select table1.timestamp, table1.value1, table1.value2, table1.valueN
     , count(tabl2.timestamp) 
 from table1 
 left join table2 
   on datediff(mi, table1.timestamp, table2.timestamp) < 10 
  and table2.timestamp > table1.timestamp
group by table1.timestamp, table1.value1, table1.value2, table1.valueN
```

Answer (score -1):

You should just need to change the `dateadd(mm,....)` to `dateadd(minute,...)` or `dateadd(mi,....)`

`mm` is the shorthand for months so when you are totaling it up for example as a date today it is adding 10 months onto the result.

This link should help you with the datetime parts and the associated codes:

[DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the point out (it was a typo from my side, corrected)